# A tricky little 3D shape

Tags: geometry

This puzzle is not original but if OK I’m asking how many straight line cuts need to be made to a rectangle (not-folded) so that it can be then made into the shape below. No gluing is needed.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in

> 3

Just

> Make two parallel cuts on one side, and then a third cut on the opposite side. Then flip *half* of the paper.

Please excuse my bad drawing:

> The dark lines are where the cuts would be (imagine they are straight) and the dotted blue line is where you would "flip" half of the paper, once you had made the cuts.
>
>
>  [image: slightly better than the last one]

Comment: That's exactly it!

Comment: Actually, if you make a fold first, you can make the two parallel lines from the same side in a single cut. (so 2 cuts needed). Im wondering if clever folding would let you do it in one cut... (NVM - just noticed OP mentioned 'not folded' in question)

Comment: We need an animated illustration!

Comment: @Raystafarian Sounds like you just volunteered to make me one.

Comment: Honestly, I can't even figure it out using real paper, ha

Comment: You might've meant a picture halfway between the two versions you put up, question_asker. Here's a re-edited version, http://i.stack.imgur.com/TfQIp.png

Comment: @humn That works too - the middle section (between the two parallel cuts) needs to be folded up, so the dashed line should extend to the second parallel line like yours does, but it also needs to extend to the left edge, like mine does. I just wanted to illustrate that you only need move one half of the paper once the cuts have been made (plus, technically, a little movement of that middle section)

Comment: @humn ah, I see what you're saying. OK, I'll change what I said: the dashed line represents the axis about which the adjoining areas of paper need to be rotated

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you didn't say "fold"

Comment: @humn No no, I was explaining it badly!